# One app, two comps, two different appearances

Tags: c#

I have an  simple app with ToolStrip, ToolStripDropDownButton as its subs and ToolStripMenuItem as its subs.

In ctor (or Load) I call temporary method (showing below) for toolstrip.

On one computer all controls are colorized: toolstrip, dropdownbuttons and items. On another computer only toolstrip and dropdownbuttons are colorized (items are not colorized).

Both computers have Win 7 64, Net Framework 4.5. App: Windows Forms in C#.

Can someone explain how it is possible and how to fix it?

```
void ColorSubItems(object obj, Color color) {
        if(obj.GetType() == typeof(ToolStrip)) {
            ((ToolStrip)obj).BackColor = color;
            foreach(ToolStripItem i in ((ToolStrip)obj).Items) {
                i.BackColor = color;
                ColorSubItems(i, color);
            }
        }
        else if(obj.GetType() == typeof(ToolStripDropDownButton)) {
            ((ToolStripDropDownButton)obj).BackColor = color;
            foreach(ToolStripDropDownItem i in
                 ((ToolStripDropDownButton)obj).DropDownItems
            ) {
                i.BackColor = color;
                ColorSubItems(i, color);
            }
        }
        else if(obj.GetType() == typeof(ToolStripMenuItem)) {
            ((ToolStripMenuItem)obj).BackColor = color;
            foreach(
                 ToolStripMenuItem i in (
                    (ToolStripMenuItem)obj).DropDownItems
            ) {
                i.BackColor = color;
                ColorSubItems(i, color);
            }
        }
        else {
            ((ToolStripItem)obj).BackColor = color;
        }
    }
```

Comment: i would expect it to be a setting on the other computer rather than code. something that changes default appearences

Comment: I added click event to subs fireing MessageBox with color name. It showing proper color but display common Control back color.

Comment: im not refering to code, im talking about system settings.

Comment: What settings you mean? Behavior of application might relay of these colors but now I have started to doubt on it.

Comment: Appearance settings

Comment: Yes, it's really true! I've commented "Application.EnableVisualStyles()" and I have what I wanted. Very thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check if one of the computers has a color scheme changed or a custom theme installed. WinForms are outdated and are enviroment dependant e.g.use system colors and fonts to build their appearance, you can never guarantee that they will look the same on all computers, consider migrating to WPF.

Comment: Thanks and big thanks for Takarii. I've deleted line Application.EnableVisualStyles() in generated file Program.cs and app works like I wanted.

Comment: Also we can leave Application.EnableVisualStyles() line but change toolStrip.RenderMode to be other than "System".